# Issue with mongoose.save never returning inside of promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

#### Update !!

I fixed my initial issue with the help of Dacre Denny answer below however when writing tests for my code it turned out that the changes were not being saved before the server responded therefor the company collection in my test database was empty, I fixed this issue with the following code

```
  Companies.find({ company_name: company.company_name }).then(found => {
    if (found.length !== 0) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "Company already exists" });
    }

    var userForms = company.users;
    company.users = [];
    const finalCompany = new Companies(company);
    console.log(finalCompany);

    var userPromises = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < userForms.length; x++) {
      var user = userForms[x].user;
      user.company = finalCompany._id;
      userPromises.push(userCreation(user));
    }
    return Promise.all(userPromises).then(responses => {
      for (var x in responses) {
        if (!responses[x].errors) {
          finalCompany.addUser(responses[x]._id);
        } else {
          res.status(400).json(responses[x]);
        }
      }
      return finalCompany;
    });
  })
  // I moved the save in here !!!
  .then((finalCompany) => {
      finalCompany.save().then(()=>{
        res.status(200).json({signup:"Successful"});
      })
  },(err) => {
      res.json({error: err});
  });
});
```

#### Original Issue

I am trying to create a mongoose document to represent a company, this code saves the model in my db however it does not seem to be responding with a status code or reply to postman when I make a request

I've used a debugger to step through the code but I am very rusty on my JS and I am afraid I've gone into deep water with promises thats gone over my head.

```
router.post('/c_signup', auth.optional, (req, res, next) => {

  const { body: { company } } = req;

  var error_json = cbc(company);

  if( error_json.errors.length > 0 ){
    return res.status(422).json(error_json);
  }

  Companies.find({company_name: company.company_name})
  .then((found) => {
    if (found.length !== 0) {
      return res.status(400).json({error: "Company already exists"});
    }

    var userForms = company.users;
    company.users = [];
    const finalCompany = new Companies(company);

    var userPromises = [];
    for (var x =0; x < userForms.length; x ++) {
      var user = userForms[x].user;
      user.company = finalCompany._id;
      userPromises.push(userCreation(user));
    }

    Promise.all(userPromises).then((responses) => {
      for (var x in responses){
        if (!responses[x].errors){
          finalCompany.addUser(responses[x]._id);
        }
        else {
          res.status(400).json(responses[x]);
        }
      }
      console.log("h2");
      finalCompany.save(function () {
        console.log("h3");
        return res.status(200);
      });
    })
  });

  return res.status(404);
});
```

This is the output from the debug but the execution is hanging here

```
h2
h3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

First, the `save()` function is asynchronous. You'll need to account for that by ensuring the promise that `save()` returns, is returned to the handler that it's is called in.

The same is true with the call to `Promise.all()` - you'll need to add that promise to the respective promise chain by returning that promise to the enclosing handler (see notes below).

Also, make sure the request handler returns a response either via `res.json()`, `res.send()`, etc, or by simply calling `res.end()`. That signals that the request has completed and should address the "hanging behaviour".

Although your code includes `res.json()`, there are many cases where it's not guaranteed to be called. In such cases, the hanging behaviour would result. One way to address this would be to add `res.end()` to the end of your promise chain as shown below:

```
Companies.find({ company_name: company.company_name }).then(found => {
  if (found.length !== 0) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: "Company already exists" });
  }

  var userForms = company.users;
  company.users = [];
  const finalCompany = new Companies(company);

  var userPromises = [];
  for (var x = 0; x < userForms.length; x++) {
    var user = userForms[x].user;
    user.company = finalCompany._id;
    userPromises.push(userCreation(user));
  }

  /* Add return, ensure that the enclosing then() only resolves
after "all promises" here have completed */
  return Promise.all(userPromises).then(responses => {
    for (var x in responses) {
      if (!responses[x].errors) {
        finalCompany.addUser(responses[x]._id);
      } else {
        res.status(400).json(responses[x]);
      }
    }
    console.log("h2");

    /* Add return, ensure that the enclosing then() only resolves
    after the asnyc "save" has completed */
    return finalCompany.save(function() {
      console.log("h3");
      return res.status(200);
    });
  });
})
.then(() => {
    res.end();
},(err) => {
    console.error("Error:",err);
    res.end();
});
```

Comment: Hey, I have updated my code and it works great however the save does not complete until after the response which I learned after trying to writes some tests for my API, is there any way to force the save callback to happen before the res.end in the last call back ?

Comment: Not to worry, fixed the issue and updated my original post to reflect it, thanks again

Comment: Hey sorry for the delay getting back to you - just read your message now - let me know if there's anything else I can help with